# How to make non-editable pdf using flying saucer

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, flying-saucer

I am using Thymeleaf + Flying Saucer for generating PDF files. How can I make non-editable PDF using Flying Saucer?

Comment: Looking briefly at the docs I see no such option. Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a frequent question with a NO answer since a PDF could not be a viewable valid PDF unless it is composed of editable binary objects. The ONLY way a PDF is "non editable" is if it is corrupt (invalid) or (100% valid) locked against viewing by anyone other than the source owner.

As soon as a PDF is decrypted for viewing it is available for manipulation by any PDF reader/editor such as Acrobat or one that ignores DRM.